# Purchase Receipts / Allocations import possibility

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to implement a text file import to the Allocations popup screen / grid on the Purchase Receipts screen?  I know there is a way to add the file import functionality to a normal grid by adding an attribute to its data view - but this doesn't seem like a normal grid screen.  My thought was to use the web service for Purchase Receipts, but before I try that I wanted to submit this question to see if it's possible to directly import to that Allocation screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to import data into the Allocations popup screen / grid on the Purchase Receipts screen either though Integration Scenarios or by using the web service for Purchase Receipts.

Comment: Any idea where I can find an example of using the web service?  My thought was to import the file into the business logic and loop through using the IO namespace, putting values in using the web service - but since this is a web based app, I'm not sure if there is another way.  I'd like to use a dialog box to select the file location, but again - being a web app, I'm not sure how that works.

Comment: Not sure that I completely understand the question. Are you working on a custom screen for Acumatica, that is supposed to show a dialog box to select the file location and import Purchase Receipts though the framework API? Or is it a 3rd party desktop application, that will show a dialog box and later connect to Acumatica Web Services to import Purchase Receipts through Screen-Based or Contact-Based API?

Comment: Thanks, Ruslan - actually, it's your first assumption.  My thought was to use a graph extension to add a button that would initiate a process of selecting a file (through a dialog box) and using that file's data to push the data into the Allocation grid via web services.  I suppose it would make more sense to just use logic in the graph extension to add allocation records directly via the cache (?) - but how to do that is a little fuzzy.